# How to remove item on an array on php using mysql database data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do something like this

---

----sql output----
name TEXT
b
c

---

```
$arr = ["a","b","c","d"];

foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    $query = "select count(*) from mydata where name = $val";
    $count = xxxx($query);
    if($count)unset($arr[$key]);
}
```

And $arr will be
 
a,d

Any simple way to do it but not checking every single element?

---

---edited---
I think I solve my problem myself...getting some inspired from mrlore that using having.

```
$arr = ["a","b","c","d"]; /* make the string inside arr safe for query */
$val = array_map(function($val){return "'$val'";},$arr);
$q = "select name from mydata where name in (" . implode(',',$val) .")";
$all = xxxxx($q);
$arr = array_diff($arr,$all);
```

This took me 0.8 second. Using my old way take 46 second and RST way takes 2 seconds.

---

---edited----
I have over 200k rows of data in my database, so I want a better way to optimize it.

---

--re MrLore--
ps : I don't know how to use stackoverflow to posting comments..so I just edit my post.

I have tried it on my mysql workbench but it does not seem to work for me.

```
select name from mydata  
where name in("a","b","c","d")  
having count(name) = 0
```

-- returns nothing

```
select name from mydata  
where name in("a","b","c","d")  
having count(name) > 0
```

Comment: Concentrating SQL statement with user input is dangerous(sql injection) try using prepared statements. Have a look at php PDO

Comment: What's with all those dashed lines and remarks in your question? Mind cleaning it up so it makes some sense?

Comment: @MightyPork Sorry.I am new on stackoverflow.I don't know how to use those formatting yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = ["a","b","c","d"];

    $query = "select DISTINCT name from mydata";
    $results = <result of query>;

    foreach ($results as $result){
      if(($key = array_search($result, $arr)) !== false) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
      }
    }
```

Or the other way around

```
    foreach ($arr as $key=>$value){
      if( in_array( $value, $results) ) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
      }
    }
```

By querying `DISTINCT` the database only returns unique values. You can then compare them with the array you have and remove them.

Comment: I got over 200k data on my database. so i want some better way to  optimize it.mostly my php array are smaller then the one that already on my database.

Comment: I guess in_array will made it more slow.its over 200k data from sql and 3000 data from array.

Comment: Another approach would be to add the `$arr` contents to a (temporary) table as `name` and query for the `name` entries in temporary table that are not present in table `mydata`

Comment: I'm getting "MySQL server has gone away" error using my method.So i'm going to temporary using yours.Thanks for helping.

Comment: there are other array functions , one sounds like a good candidate for the job - array_intersect()